# Google Maps: mark road as Closed on iPhone/mobile (Directions)

Tags: setup, google-maps

Is there a way to mark a road as Closed in Google Maps Directions on a mobile phone (iPhone but likely to be the same on Android)?

So that the itinerary is changed, avoiding that closed road.

[image]

*Note*<sup>1</sup> on the desktop version the road is to be "report as closed", but didn't see that on the mobile version.

*Note*<sup>2</sup> any other solution that makes Maps avoid that road is welcome as well.

Comment: There is a workaround:  Mark it as closed on the Waze mobile app.  As that is owned by Google it feeds into Google Maps.

Comment: Are you sure? Yesterday met a road that was closed in Waze by someone else, but G Maps didn't have it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can’t report a road closure when using directions.

You can do it by going in Contribute tab > Edit map > Report a problem with map data > Selected the road > “Closed Road”.

Note that it won’t be closed on the map until an employee verifies it manually (it can take up to a month).

As @chenmunka suggested it you can also report it as closed on Waze, some of the closures are shared to Google Maps.